# How to disable the TypeScript compiler's watch mode

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular quickstart to go through the tutorial and I notice that whenever I make a change, even without saving any of those changes, my browser refreshes automatically.  This has the effect of causing my computer to work harder than necessary.  I'm fine manually refreshing when I'm ready to see my changes.

I've tried adding `"watch": false` to my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "watch": false
  }
}
```

After restarting `npm start` it doesn't appear to have changed anything.

I tried removing the `-w` switch from the compiler command in `package.json` but that doesn't have done any good either.

I made sure my IDE (WebStorm) isn't auto-saving changes.

What do I have to do to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

> I notice that whenever I make a change, even without saving any of those changes, my browser refreshes automatically.

Browser reloading isn't done by TypeScript.